# How to implement delete without returning unit/void using retrofit?

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit

I've got the root of the problem of this implmenetation:
[How to delete with Body using retrofit with usecase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970852/how-to-delete-with-body-using-retrofit-with-usecase)

In brief:

1. With this usecase method like underneath I return `Unit`.
2. My logs didn't show it directly, but in debugger I have seen that the problem is because of

```
Service methods cannot return void.
    for method NotificationApi.deleteToken

        if (e.isSameExceptionAs(fromDownstream) || e.isCancellationCause(coroutineContext)) {
```

1. How to change this method `deleteToken` to work with delete and not return void/unit?
2. How to provide it with usecase properly?

Thanks.

This is my UseCase

```
class DeleteTokenSecondUseCase @Inject constructor(private val api: NotificationApi) :
    BaseApiRequestUseCase<DeleteTokenSecondUseCase.Params, Unit>() {
    override fun create(params: Params): Flow<Unit> = flow {
        api.deleteToken(NotificationApi.TokenChangedBody(params.token))

    }

    data class Params(val token: String)
}
```

this is my delete

```
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "account/firebase", hasBody = true)
    fun deleteToken(@Body body: TokenChangedBody)

    data class TokenChangedBody(val token: String)
```

fun method in vm

```
    fun notifyNotificationTokenChanged(token: String) {

        val params = DeleteTokenSecondUseCase.Params(token)
        deleteTokenSecondUseCase.buildWithState(params)
            .withSuccess { Log.d("build", "WORKS $params") }
            .withError {  Log.d("build", "NOT WORKS $params")  }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

EDIT:
I have implmeneted it with `Call` event but still it goes onFailure, guys why?

```
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "account/firebase", hasBody = true)
    fun deleteToken(@Body body: TokenChangedBody) : Call<ResponseBody>
```

```
    fun notifyNotificationTokenChanged(token: String) {

        val params = NotificationApi.TokenChangedBody(token)
        val deleteRequest: Call<ResponseBody> = notificationApi.deleteToken(params)
        deleteRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, response: Response<ResponseBody?>?) {
                Log.d("apitoken", "WORKS")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("apitoken", "DOESNT WORK")
            }
        })
}
```

EDIT2:
WORKS!

SOLUTION

```
    fun notifyNotificationTokenChanged(token: String) {

        val params = NotificationApi.TokenChangedBody(token)
        val deleteRequest: Call<Void> = notificationApi.deleteToken(params)
        deleteRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<Void?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void?>?, response: Response<Void?>?) {
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void?>?, t: Throwable?) {
            }
        })
    }
```

```
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "account/firebase", hasBody = true)
    fun deleteToken(@Body body: TokenChangedBody) : Call<Void>
```

Someone told in Kotlin use `:Completable`, but haven't test it.
stackoverflow.com/questions/35429481/retrofit-2-void-return

Comment: If you want to delete an item from a RecyclerView without Retrofit, but simply using Kotin, please check [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: Thank man, but not exactly -> I would like to request @Delete service to backend using Body and then backend implemnet further steps. What do you think about it?
I thnk I could just change this implementation above to have accepted by retrofit

Comment: I have found 
@GET("/foo")
Call<Foo> getFoo();, but is it possible to not use callback just flows or coroutines?